# How to re-use Drupal module code using module_load_include

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, code-reuse, include-path

I am using the node_clone module with great effect but there is a need in my project to use node_clone functions from my custom module. So I put in the following code:

```
module_load_include('inc', 'node_clone', 'clone.pages');

function mymodule_init(){
    clone_node_save(118);
}
```

That code returns `Fatal error: Call to undefined function clone_node_save()`.

My modules are categorized by source into directories labelled **mine** and **contrib**. Node_save is in contrib while myModule is in mine.

So, I amended the code acordingly as follows:

```
module_load_include('inc', '../../contrib/node_clone', 'clone.pages');
```

but I get the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit misleading, the folder is named 'node_clone' but the module is actually called 'clone', so you want:

```
module_load_include('inc', 'clone', 'clone.pages');
```

`hook_init()` runs pretty early on so if you don't need the clone module's functions before hand, you'd be better off moving the code into the hook:

```
function mymodule_init(){
  module_load_include('inc', 'clone', 'clone.pages');
  clone_node_save(118);
}
```

Comment: "hook_init() runs pretty early..." part could be written in ALL CAPS and within <h1> tags :). Consider moving your code to an appropriate node hook or something.

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/all/modules/contrib/node_clone/clone.pages.inc';
```

From the [module_load_include API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/7):

> Do not use this function in a global context since it requires Drupal
>   to be fully bootstrapped, use `require_once DRUPAL_ROOT .
>   '/path/file'` instead.

Comment: Good call, I never knew that about `module_load_include()`